# Reading a markdown file as a variable and converting the variable to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, markdown

I´m trying to convert a local md file to json in my API, but I get syntax errors.

The problem seems to be that when I read the file and store it as a string variable, it gets stored without the new rows that are required by md2json to work. When I console log the variable it gets printed line by line looking just like the md file, but I cannot convert it. When I send it as a respone and print it on my page it prints:

```
# Air ## The second largest heading ###### The smallest heading
```

But the original md file looks like this:

```
# Air

## The second largest heading

###### The smallest heading
```

This is what I´ve tried:

```
const md2json = require('md-2-json');
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    let content = fs.readFileSync('directory/file.md','utf8')
    console.log(content)
    res.send(content)
})
```

Is there some way to make this work, or is there some other better way to do it?
I saw some posts about XMLHttpRequest but didn´t really get it to work.

//* Edit:
I now saw that I forgot to include the converting; this is what it´s supposed to look like when using md2json:

```
router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    let content = fs.readFileSync('directory/file.md','utf8')
    console.log(content)
    let newContent = md2json.parse(content)
    console.log(newContent)
    res.send(newContent)
})
```

//* Edit 2:
The lack of \n doesn´t seem to be the problem, since this works:

```
let mdInput = `# Air ## The second largest heading ###### The smallest heading`

router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    let newContent = md2json.parse(mdInput)
    console.log(newContent)
    res.send(newContent)
```

But this doesn´t:

```
let mdInput = `
# Air

## The second largest heading
 
##### The smallest heading
`

router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    let newContent = md2json.parse(mdInput)
    console.log(newContent)
    res.send(newContent)
```

Comment: And why do you say it can't convert it? Do you get any error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'The smallest heading')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it : it is because this lib seems to allow h(n) to live only in h(n-1) so a h6 can't be directly in a h2, so this should solve your problem :

```
# Air

## The second largest heading

### The third largest heading
#### The fourth largest heading
##### The second smallest heading

###### The smallest heading
```

```
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    const content = fs.readFileSync('directory/file.md','utf8').toString()
    let newContent = md2json.parse(content)
    res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>${ newContent }</body></html>`)
})
```

Comment: Interesting! Now I get no type errors, but the output on my page is now "[object Object]" instead of json data?

Comment: Now when I just send it like "res.send(newContent)", I get the json data, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to send it with a little bit of html :

```js
const md2json = require('md-2-json');
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/page', (req, res) => {
    const content = fs.readFileSync('directory/file.md','utf8').toString()
    let newContent = md2json.parse(content)
    res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>${ newContent }</body></html>`)
})
```

Comment: Look at the end of my now edited post!

Comment: Doesn't it work ?

Comment: No, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'The smallest heading')"

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your parsing library directly (or with you file), what does it print for `content` and `newContent` ? And at which line does it mark the error ?

Comment: The error is in "node_modules\md-2-json\index.js:24:43"

Comment: It means it's a problem with your lib itself (or your file). Have you tried another lib to verify whether it's the lib or the file the problem (or maybe try casting file content to string (see my updated answer))

Comment: I have not tried another library, do you have one you recommend? Your new answer gave the same type error btw.

Comment: Look at something online like https://dillinger.io for example (the first link).

Comment: btw, I looked at your lib more in details but do you want to get the AST of the md (which means you have to render it yourself) or directly the html (which means no more work nut less freedom on your UI)

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean by that last comment :)

Comment: the lib you used returns a json objects which to need to render yourself (you give the md, the give you back the json, that you then parse and render to html), but other ones does that for you (you give the md, the give you back the html)

Comment: Okey, now I get it! I would like is not rendered, just json. I´m in a school project and my specific task is to make my api read md and spit out json.

Answer (score 0):

Your page prints everything in one line because html ignores `\n` as a new line character by default

```html
# Air

## The second largest heading

###### The smallest heading
```

You have to wrap your text with `pre` tag

```html
<pre>
# Air

## The second largest heading

###### The smallest heading
</pre>
```

You can also use `white-space: pre` css property or replace `\n` with `<br>`

Comment: Yes, this does fix the markdown part, but I forgot to include the converting to json, which I´ve now added, and this does not work then since it´s no longer only markdown which is what I would need it to be. But it solved the problem as you understood it!